# Node Js Async doesnt run in the Correct order and Skips promises

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm currently having problems with the async/await Syntax. And for the last 2 days, I'm trying to find out why and finally decided to ask.

I'm trying to run a cron function(test) that calls an async function that connects to a database and tries to find new information regarding each entry with a 3rd party API.

Each function works on its own but when combining them they don't run in the correct order and the first function skips the await statement at the first row.(still executes it)

Output looks like the following(undefined -> DB entries -> api results)

The corret should look like (DB entries -> api results -> final results)

```
async function test() {
    var db = await checkfornewdata() // executes 
    console.log(db) //skips line one and returns undefined as it didnt get its value
}
```

```
async function checkfornewdata()
{
    
    var state = `SELECT * FROM users`;
    var users= []
    var newusers

    console.log('Get connection ...');

     connection.query(state , async function (err,result) {
      if(err) throw err;
      users= result
     console.log('Query Result')
     console.log(result) //works without problems

     for (var i in result){ 

       var checknew= await 3rdpartyapi.getusers(i.id );
       if (i.joinDate> checknew.joinDate){
         newusers.push(i);
     }
     console.log('New entries:')
     console.log(newusers)
     connection.end()
     return newusers;
  }
```

```
async function getusers(id)
{
var joinDate;   

if (typeof(id) !== 'undefined'){

console.log("getting joinDate of " + id)
await 3rdpartyapi.getUser(id).then(User => {    
        
joindate= User.joinDate;
console.log(joinDate)   //last output i recieve

})
.catch((err) => {
    
console.log(err)    

return err;
})
return joinDate;
}}
```

Comment: Why you are mixing up both promise and async-await. 
convert all promise to async await and add all code inside the function to a try-catch. you will get error in catch . also what is this element checkfornewdata function ?

Comment: i fixed it, i accidentally copied a wronf commit there, ofc its result everywhere. The promise function was from the 3rd party website and i just copied and modified it a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `checkfornewdata` function, you're mixing promises and callbacks. In its current form your function returns before the call to the database finishes. (that's why `console.log(db)` returns `undefined`).

To fix this, you can use a mysql driver that supports promises (like [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper)) or rewrite your function like this:

```
function checkfornewdata() {
    // ...    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(state , async (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        // ...
        resolve(newusers);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i wrote everything to mysql2 and now the syntax i used works, thanks a lot